# Sum nested lists with recursive function

Tags: python, nested-lists

Hi i have a nested list which i should sum it from recursive function
how can i do that?
my solution didn't work

```
def n_l_sum(n):
    s=0
    for i in n:
        if i==list:
            s+=i
        else:
            s+=n_l_s(n)
    return s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def n_l_s(n):
    s=0
    for i in n:
        if type(i) != type([]):
            s+=i
        else:
            s+=n_l_s(i)
    return s
n=[3, -1, [2, -2], [6, -3, [4, -4]]]
print(n_l_s(n))
```

output:

```
5
```

Answer (score 1):

use the isinstanceof function instead of using the ==

```
def summer(lst):
    if not isinstance(lst, list) : return lst

    sum = 0

    for x in lst:
        sum += summer(x)
    return sum


def main():
    a= [1,2,3, [5,6]]

    print(summer(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion can be quite difficult to grasp at first; because it can be very intuitive to conceptualize but an pain to implement. I will try to explain my answer as thoroughly as possible so that you understand what exactly is happening:

```
def n_l_sum(n,i):
    s=0 #somewhere to store our sum 
    lenLst= len(n)  
    cur = n[i] #sets current element to 'cur'
    if lenLst-1-i < 1: #this is the base case 
        return cur
    else:
        s = n_l_sum(n,i+1)+cur #where the actual iteration happens
        print(s) #give result 
        return s 

n=[6,4]
n_l_sum(n,0)
```

### The Base Case

The first important thing to understand is the ***base case*** this gives the recursion a way of stopping.

For example without it the function would return an `IndexError` because eventually `n_l_sum(n,i+1)` would eventually go over the maximum index. Therefore `lenLst-1-i < 1` stops this; what it is saying: if there is only one element left *do this*.

### Understanding Recursion

Next, I like to think of recursion as a mining drill that goes deep into the ground and collects its bounty back on the way up to the surface. This brings us to ***stack frames*** you can think of these as depths into the ground (0-100 m, 100-200 m). In terms of programming they are literal frames which store different **instances** of variables. In this example `cur` will be `4` in frame 1 then `6` in frame 2.

once we hit the ***base case*** we go back up through the frames this is where `s = n_l_sum(n,i+1)+cur` does the legwork and calculates the sum for us.

If you are still struggling to understand recursion try and run this code through http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit to see what is happening on a variable level.

Answer (score 0):

The functional way would be to to this:

```
def list_sum(l):
    if not isinstance(l, list):  # recursion stop, l is a number
        return l

    # do list_sum over each element of l, sum result
    return sum(map(list_sum, l))
```